# 'Recently active' and 'Newest' sort don't work for the new navigation layout

Tags: support, bug, sorting, new-nav

Compare:

[image: New Question Sorted by newest]

With

[image: New Questions Sorted by Recently active]

The Newest of the new questions at that point is from 2013:

[image: The 'Newest' question]

How do the sort methods actually work? Is this what's intended or are they broken?